# create an outlook rule to create folders if needed based on text in subject line

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking for a clear way to use vba to read subject line of email when received in order to either create a new folder or just use existing folder to move the email into. I have seen some vba examples but none address the new mail methods found in the vba editor with outlook.

Comment: Check out [this article](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62), specifically methods 2 and 3, I guess that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I JUST wrote code for this. My macro searches emails for a specific string and then takes everything after that and creates a folder using that name. You'll need a few functions to:
1) Check to see if the folder already exists
2) Create it if it doesn't
3) Move the MailItem to the new folder
4) Call those functions

NOTE: Much of this is hard-coded and could be changed to take user input if desired. Also, it will not work for sub-folders (you'll have to customize that).

1) Check for folder:

```
Function CheckForFolder(strFolder As String) As Boolean

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim FolderToCheck As Outlook.MAPIFolder


    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    On Error Resume Next
    Set FolderToCheck = olInbox.Folders(strFolder)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not FolderToCheck Is Nothing Then
        CheckForFolder = True
    End If

ExitProc:
    Set FolderToCheck = Nothing
    Set olInbox = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Function
```

2) Create:

```
Function CreateSubFolder(strFolder As String) As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set CreateSubFolder = olInbox.Folders.Add(strFolder)

    ExitProc:
    Set olInbox = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Function
```

3) Search and move:

```
Function SearchAndMove(lookFor As String)

 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Dim FolderToCheck As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Dim myItem As Object
 Dim MyFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Dim lookIn As String
 Dim newName As String
 Dim location As Integer


 Set olApp = Outlook.Application
 Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
     For Each myItem In olInbox.Items
     lookIn = myItem.Subject
     If InStr(lookIn, lookFor) Then
         location = InStr(lookIn, lookFor)
                 newName = Mid(lookIn, location)
            If CheckForFolder(newName) = False Then
                Set MyFolder = CreateSubFolder(newName)
                myItem.Move MyFolder
                    Else
                Set MyFolder = olInbox.Folders(newName)
                myItem.Move MyFolder
            End If
        End If
    Next myItem
End Function
```

4) call function:

```
Sub myMacro()
    Dim str as String
    str = "Thing to look for in the subjectline"
    SearchAndMove (str)

End Sub
```

Comment: You could make this 10x simpler by not creating the functions... oh well.