# Outlook vba to create folder and file emails based on subject phrase

Tags: vba, outlook

I found this [create an outlook rule to create folders if needed based on text in subject line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098893/create-an-outlook-rule-to-create-folders-if-needed-based-on-text-in-subject-line)

Which gets me 99% of the way there. But I would like the reference point to create the folder name to start after a set character. For example if the subjet was "xxxx #1234", I want the folder name to be 1234, not #1234 as would happen if I put the str value as #. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to get a substring, see [String Manipulation](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/string-manipulation.html)
 for more information about string VBA functions.

For example, to get number you can use the Right function:

```
MsgBox Right("xxxx #1234", 4)
```