# Create a folder based on domain and in that folder create a folder based on sender name

Tags: vba, outlook

I want a macro/rule/code that creates a folder in Outlook based on the sender's domain, after that I want it to create a folder based on the sender's name in the sender's domain folder, and then move the mail to that folder.

I am thinking of a folder layout like this:

> Inbox\@senders domain\@Senders name\Email.msg

Comment: In order to create folders on the go, you need VBA to handle all inbound emails from a Rule. But note this way only works when Outlook is running.

Comment: Other than the *creation* of folders, you can do all of that without VBA, using Rules. ([rules for domains](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/create-rules-that-apply-to-an-entire-domain/) as well as [Create folder based on email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5098893/8112776))

Comment: Note that you may need to re-enable the "run a script" option in Rule actions, which was removed by Microsoft at some point for security reasons. See [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306108/how-to-create-a-script-for-the-rules-wizard-in-outlook) and [this](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/run-a-script-rule-action-is-no-longer-working-or-available).  Also - welcome! Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this code, however, you may need to change something as your special request.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace

  ' set object reference to default Inbox
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
' fires when new item added to default Inbox
' (per Application_Startup)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim targetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim senderName As String

  ' don't do anything for non-Mailitems
  If TypeName(item) <> "MailItem" Then GoTo ProgramExit

  Set Msg = item

  ' move received email to target folder based on sender name
  senderName = Msg.senderName

  If CheckForFolder(senderName) = False Then  ' Folder doesn't exist
    Set targetFolder = CreateSubFolder(senderName)
  Else
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set targetFolder = _
    objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(senderName)
  End If

  Msg.Move targetFolder

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub

Function CheckForFolder(strFolder As String) As Boolean
' looks for subfolder of specified folder, returns TRUE if folder exists.
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim FolderToCheck As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

' try to set an object reference to specified folder
On Error Resume Next
Set FolderToCheck = olInbox.Folders(strFolder)
On Error Goto 0

If Not FolderTocheck Is Nothing Then
  CheckForFolder = True
End If

ExitProc:
Set FolderToCheck = Nothing
Set olInbox = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Function

Function CreateSubFolder(strFolder As String) As Outlook.MAPIFolder
' assumes folder doesn't exist, so only call if calling sub knows that
' the folder doesn't exist; returns a folder object to calling sub
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set CreateSubFolder = olInbox.Folders.Add(strFolder)

ExitProc:
Set olInbox = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Function
```

More information, please see,

[Create new folder for new sender name and move message into new folder](https://superuser.com/questions/489124/create-new-folder-for-new-sender-name-and-move-message-into-new-folder)

Comment: Thanks for the above code, I have that code running and it works ok, not the full way.
It Creates the senders folder, wich is correct, but It didnt create the "senders domain" folder frist and in the senders domain folder create the senders name.

I really appreciate the effort, but it didnt work the full way:(
If some1 can modify the above code so that it does the following
Create "senders" domain name as a folder(has to be checked ofcourse)
and in the domain create a folder with Senders Name, and then move the msg into the senders names folder wich is in the domain name folder.